# UnityPlayerActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API

Tags: unity, android, google-play-services

I am making a simple 2D game. When I imported the Google Play Ads Services, it is showing some error when I build it:

> \Temp\gradleOut\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\unity3d\player\UnityPlayerActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
>
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>
>   Execution failed for task ':launcher:bundleReleaseResources'.
>
>   1 exception was raised by workers:
>
>   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
>
>   E:\unity\SaveME\Save-Me\Temp\gradleOut\launcher\build\intermediates\bundle_manifest\release\processReleaseManifest\bundle-manifest\AndroidManifest.xml:40: error: unexpected element `<queries>` found in `<manifest>`.
> - Try:
>
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Comment: Sounds like you may be targeting an outdated version. You should walk us through your Android build settings, and the exact steps you took to import the Google Play Ads Services — it's possible you've followed instructions for an old version that is no longer supported.